# LINQ counting unique strings in a list and storing the values in a tuple

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have a  `list<strings[]> doc` and I want to store their counts into a `Tuple<string[], int[]>` (unique words, number of n words in each list entry). So far I only got the unique strings

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string[]> doc = new List<string[]>();
        string[] a = { "That", "is", "a", "cat" };
        string[] b = { "That", "bat", "flew","over","the", "cat" };
        doc.Add(a);
        doc.Add(b);

        string[] strs  = doc
            .SelectMany(array => array)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();

        foreach (string val in strs)  {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
}
```

So the output should be something like

```
string[] a = { "That","is","a","cat","bat","flew","over"," the" };
int[] i_one = { 1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0 };
int[] i_two ={ 1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 };

List<Tuple<string[],int[]> ret =  new List<string[],int[]>();

var b = new Tuple<string[],int[]>(a, i_one);
var c = new Tuple<string[],int[]>(a, i_two);
ret.Add(b);
ret.Add(c);
```

Comment: Ive read this 4 times, and im still confused what you're trying to do. what are the numbers in `i_one` and `i_two`?

Comment: @Jamiec Count the unique values in the List<string[]> and store the counts in a `Tuple<string[],int[]>`

Comment: Read all the strings into a `Dictionary<string, int>` when adding if the entry exists increment the count by 1.  Once done convert the dictionary into the list you want

Comment: @ccsv Does it matter where the string was? Or is all that matters is  the count?

Comment: @ccsv - you just restated the question without further info. i see 8 string entries in `a` and 8 numbers (1 or 0) in `i_one` - how are they related?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The order of the string does not matter but the string[] should include all the strings in the `List<string[]>`

Comment: @Jamiec The 8 strings are of unique words from the `List<string[]> doc` the numbers in `i_one` are the counts of the unique words in the first item in the List and `i_two` is the second item in the list

Comment: Ok, I got it now I think, but its your required result structure that is the issue, if you wanted a `List<Tuple<string,int>>` (where Item1=word, Item2=count) this would be easy (In fact at least one answer already gives you that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    var lines = new List<string[]>
    {
        new[] { "That", "is", "is", "a", "cat" },
        new[] { "That", "bat", "flew", "over", "the", "flew", "cat" }
    };

    var distinctWords = lines.SelectMany(strings => strings).Distinct().ToArray();

    var result = (
        from line in lines
        let lineWords = line.ToArray()
        let counts = distinctWords.Select(distinctWord => lineWords.Count(word => word == distinctWord)).ToArray()
        select new Tuple<string[], int[]>(distinctWords, counts)
    ).ToList();
```

See [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L6nXMd).

Comment: This seems to work except in the cases when you have more than one of the same words in line

Comment: @ccsv I'm try to correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

So something like (forgive my naming conventions its a hack)

```
    string[] a = { "That", "is", "a", "cat" };
    string[] b = { "That", "bat", "flew", "over", "the", "cat" };

    var c = a.Union(b).Distinct();
    var a1 = (from ch in c select a.Count(r => r == ch));
     var b1 = (from ch in c select b.Count(r => r == ch));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure this will solve your issue completely but I knocked this up using LinqPad, but your end result is quite difficult to achieve:

```
List<string[]> doc = new List<string[]>();
string[] a = { "That", "is", "a", "cat" };
string[] b = { "That", "bat", "flew","over","the", "cat" };
doc.Add(a);
doc.Add(b);

doc.SelectMany(array => array)
.GroupBy(x => x)
.Select(x=> new {Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count()});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It should return a list of tuples with (string = all words in the whole input list, int = counts of words in the ith row of the input list )

Comment: Yeah I know what your output should be, infact @BugFinder's answer achieves what you want, alll that is left to do on it is to tie it all together